# Is Caffe Net Surgery requires fine tuning?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am new at Caffe and I want to use already trained caffeNet model with ImageNet. I applied net surgery by removing a convolutional intermediate conv4 layer.

```
'layer {
     name: "relu3"
     type: "ReLU"
     bottom: "conv3"
     top: "conv3"
 }

 layer {
     name: "relu5-new"
     type: "ReLU"
     bottom: "conv5-new"
     top: "conv5-new"
 }

 layer {
     name: "pool5-new"
     type: "Pooling"
     bottom: "conv5-new"
     top: "pool5-new"
     pooling_param {
         pool: MAX
         kernel_size: 3
         stride: 2
      }
 }

 layer {
     name: "fc6"
     type: "InnerProduct"
     bottom: "pool5-new"
     top: "fc6"
     inner_product_param {
     num_output: 4096
     }
 }'
```

[Full of prototxt file can be found here](https://ideone.com/1PhzSs)

After saving this new network the accuracy became 0. Should I make fine tuning on ImageNet validation set, or is there something wrong on my new prototxt file?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original net you started with had `conv4` between `conv3` and `conv5`: this means the filters (weights) of `conv5` were expecting certain number of inputs and certain "order" or "meaning" of inputs. Once you removed `conv4`, you had to alter `conv5` to accept different number of inputs. Therefore, the new `conv5` layer **must** be trained to accommodate to the new inputs it receives.
In this case, when you introduced a new `conv5` layer, you should have `weight_filler` defined in your prototxt to guide caffe as to how to initialize the new weights. Otherwise caffe will set the weights to zero and it will be almost impossible to finetune in this case.

Comment: Thank you for reply at first.I tried to  initialize the new convolutional layer weights  with either `xavier` or `gaussian`. And the accuracy did not increase. I am not sure to make finetuning because I am working on imagenet validation set. Do you know any public repo that has an example like this type net surgery?

Comment: @seaSky your accuracy is zero because you severed your net in the middle. You must fine-tune it to work